How does this input buffer work in schematic from Xilinx Virtex-5 user guide?
The following is from page 302 of the Xilinx VIrtex-5 User guide: https://docs.amd.com/v/u/en-US/ug190

It seems to me like the incoming signal should go into the input buffer and then the output driver in series. But that would mean it goes into the output of an inverter, which doesn't make sense. So that must mean the incoming signal goes into "External Pin." In that case, what is the purpose of the input buffer?
Also, it says "The voltage across the gate oxide at any time must not exceed 4.05 V." Since the gate and source of N0 are grounded, does that make the Vox of N0 just equal to the drain voltage of N0, which is the voltage at External Pin? Meaning if the voltage at External Pin is greater than 4.05 V, it violates that limit?

The figure needs to be read in context; here is the pre-amble that appears before the figure:

Link for above image:  PDF page 302 of this document:
https://docs.amd.com/v/u/en-US/ug190
This document and the figure posted describe a typical GPIO connected to an external pin.  Po & No are the transistors of the 3-state output buffer.  Pi & Ni are the transistors of an input inverter.  Both are connected to the same external pin.
When Po and No are both OFF (in high impedance state, as shown in the figure you posted), then the voltage of the external pin can be determined by an external signal, ie: the pin becomes an input.  Otherwise, the pin is an output, and its voltage is set by which ever of Po and No is ON; note that Po and No cannot both be on simultaneously.

does that make the Vox of N0 just equal to the drain voltage of N0, which is the voltage at External Pin?

Yes.
The document explains that there is a maximum gate voltage that must not be exceeded.  In the case of Po and No, yes, the voltage to consider is gate-to-drain, not gate-to-source since, gate is tied to source in both cases.
However, for the input buffer transistors, the maximum gate-oxide voltage is gate-to-source.  Gate-to-drain voltage stress may be a little less, depending on the voltage drop on the transistor when it is conducting.
Regardless, the document mentions that the maximum gate oxide voltage stress for any terminal, gate-source, and gate-drain, must not exceed the stated limit.

N0 and P0 are both off -- this buffer in this configuration is non functional.
Its purpose is to provide ESD protection to the Input Buffer -- somewhat backing up the two diodes.

"External Pin" is the point where your would connect your external circuit.  It represents a physical pin on the package.
That pin can be used as either input or output.  If it is to be used as an input, the output driver will be disabled and the input signal will pass through the input buffer to internal logic.
If the pin is to be used as an output, the output driver will be enabled and the output of the input buffer will (probably) be ignored.
